# FC with app on multitask

Tags: android, android-activity

I made an app of news, and the problem is that when I go go out of the app with home button, if later I want to go in again and I use multitask, it gives me an FC. I was searching and the error occurs when the system closes my app to let some free memory. I think is something relationated with my selectActivity, I think something is wrong here because is my mainActivity and I check if is the first time that I lanched the app if not, i launch MainActivity and I close this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post some code please?

Comment: Read this [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)